# Transfer data from mutiple csv to single excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have 3 csv files and want to import all data respectively to an excel with data transferred to 3 Sheets (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3) in a single workbook using c#.net. Any help is appreciated.

```
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application;
Excel.Workbook wb = new Excel.Workbook;
Excel.Worksheet ws1 = new Excel.worksheet;
Excel.Worksheet ws2 = new Excel.worksheet;
Excel.Worksheet ws3 = new Excel.worksheet;

string csv1 = @"c:\SS1.csv";
string csv2 = @"c:\SS2.csv";
string csv3 = @"c:\SS3.csv";

wb=xl.Workbooks.Open(csv1);
```

I'm stuck here.How do i access the other 2 csv files.

Comment: dude either change your question or use the same logic as wb - and change the it to ccv2 ccv3 file names to acccess the rest

Comment: how can the same wb access multiple csv without releasing the earlier one?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question what you need is to add the rest of the csv files as `sheets` as an opened tab also with the main csv file.

So you should look for a code on `wb` object to add sheets to it.

Comment: can't add sheets in main csv.Pulling data from 3 different csv is a requirement.

Comment: let ask you do you need to open them in one file in single sheet or in separate sheet ?

Comment: 1 file but different sheets